# MongoDB Async - Find or create docs; return array of them

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback, mongoose

This is likely a simple answer but I'm relatively new to asynchronous programming and I'm looking for somebody to point me in the right direction.

My question is this - What is the best way to go about finding or creating a number of documents from an array of names (I'm using Mongoose) and then returning an array of _id's?

So to be clear, I want to:

1. Given an array of names, find or create a document with each name
2. Return an array of the existing or newly created documents _ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use async module and within it it's async.parallel() method - 
https://github.com/caolan/async#quick-examples

```
async.parallel([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
], callback);
```

Or you can use promises and then Q.all() to get the array of ids back - 
https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination

```
Q.all(arrayOfFindOps).then(function(rows) {
    return _.pluck(rows, '_id')
}
```

If you don't want to use any of the above and do it with callbacks, then you have to keep track of the count of array length, keep adding the ids to an array and when your completion counter reaches array length, call another function with the array you made.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up going with just using callbacks and keeping track of my array lengths ;) Looking forward to utilizing async and Promises in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This code can be easily modified to meet your requirements. Call this function for each document that required to be created if doesn't exist.

```
function(req, reply) {
      //   return document. if not found, create docuemnt.
      docModel.findOne( {'name': req.params.name},  function ( err , doc) {
          if(err){
              //handle error
          }
          if(doc===null){
              //find failed, time to create.
              doc = new docModel( {'name': req.params.name} );
              doc.save(function(err){
                  if(err){                              
                    //handle error
                  }
              });
          }              
          return reply(user._id);
      });
  }
```